# Using rpart Package in R, error selecting all variables for decision tree model

Tags: r, rpart

I'm trying to create a decision tree model using a dataset with 200+ variables and I'm getting this error in using the . notation for all variables.

```
fit <- rpart(first_party ~ ., data=train)
```

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(m, labs) : undefined columns selected
```

The tree models fine when I define the variables by name, but I can't do that 200 times.

```
fit <- rpart(first_party ~ Crime + Number_of_Schools + Pop_Total, data=train)
```

Comment: If you run `names(train)` does anything weird pop up in the resulting vector?

Comment: No, not really. I just get a long list of the variables: `[1] "Number_of_Independent_Schools"                                                                                                  
  [2] "Number_of_Schools"                                                                                                              
  [3] "Index of Multiple Deprivation"                                                                                                  
  [4] "Income deprivation" ` etc

Comment: It's possible that the spaces in the names are creating a problem. Run `names(train) <- stringr::str_replace_all(names(train), " ", "_")` and try again.

Comment: It wasn't that, but another variable had a \ in, which seemed to be the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed to be the \ in one of the variable names.